# regular expression find end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have troubles with a regular expression.

I want to replace all ocurrences of `myData=xxxx&` xxxx can change, but always ends with `&`, except the last ocurrence, when it is `myData=xxx`.

```
var data = "the text myData=data1& and &myData=otherData& and end myData=endofstring"
data.replace(/myData=.*?&/g,'newData');
```

it returns :

> the text newData and &newData and end myData=endofstring

which is correct, but how can I detect the last one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to assign the result of `replace` somewhere, which you're not doing in your question's code
2. You can use an *alternation* (`|`) to match either `&` or end of string

So:

```js
    var data = "the text myData=data1& and &myData=otherData& and end myData=endofstring"
    data = data.replace(/myData=.*?(?:&|$)/g,'newData');
//  ^^^^^^^-- 1                    ^^^^^^^-- 2
console.log(data);
```

Note the use of a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`), to limit the scope of the alternation.

Comment: Would it be correct to use [&$\.] instead of (?:&|$) ?

Comment: @MC93: Why do you say that? It will replace the last occurrence even if it isn't at the end of the string, provided it's followed by `&` (which it pretty much would have to be).

Comment: @Poyke: No. `[&$]` looks for the *characters* `&` and `$`.

Comment: looking at his question again he did add a . at the end of the last occurrence so you can look for & or $ or \.  using your correct syntax

Comment: @Poyke: I think that's just the end of the sentence in the question; there's no `.` at the end of the last occurrence in the quoted example.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
data="myData=abc& and linked with something else";
data.replace(/myData=.*?&/g,'newData');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ob8c2j9v/